# Python : pass an exception in a loop

Tags: python, exception

i'm stuck with my simple code, i'm a newbie for coding.. I'm using python and
In my list i have bad values that made exceptions (httperror : 404) . I want to ignore this exceptions and continue my loop. But with my code, the print("Http error") loop again and again. I don't know how to pass this exception to loop the entire code again.

```
while i < len(list_siret):   
    try : 
        data = api.siret(list_sirets[i]).get()
        str_datajs = json.dumps(data, indent= 4)
        a_json = json.loads(str_datajs)
        i +=1
        print("test1", i ,str_datajs)    
    except urllib.error.URLError : 
        print("Http error")
        pass
```

Comment: You are returning to the loop, it just keep throwing `URLError`.

Comment: This is most likely caused by the fact that you're constraining the `except` clause with `urllib.error.URLError` exception. But your code can also raise Exceptions from JSON decodes... IF you want to pass ALL errors, then remove `urllib.error.URLError`.

Comment: @Xelvoz That is not what OP is asking, and catching all exceptions is a very bad practice

Comment: @DeepSpace That is true. It was a big "IF", but your solution seem most appropriate :)

Comment: Note that `i += 1` is only executed if `api.siret` does not raise an exception. If you move that to a `finally` clause, you would actually proceed to the next URL (though you would still see "Http error" for each failing URL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have `print("Http error")` inside the `except` block, it will be executed every time the exception occurs.

Consider the more idiomatic approach below:

```
for siret in list_siret:
    try:
        data = api.siret(siret).get()
    except urllib.error.URLError:
        continue
    str_datajs = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
    a_json = json.loads(str_datajs)
    print("test1", i ,str_datajs)
```

We iterate directly over `list_siret` without needing to index into it and manually manage `i`, and instead of `pass`ing we just move to the next element in the list in case an exception was raised.